# Wait for a child process in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS process that loads some page and then it needs to call a go-process to analyze the page and to decide what page should be loaded next. go-process takes a while to execute. My problem is that CasperJS doesn't wait for the go-process to complete and exits.

```
casper.then(function(){
  var p = cp.execFile('/path/parse', [], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
  });

});
```

How can I wait for my child process to complete?

Answer (score 6):

All `then*` and `wait*` functions are scheduling steps to be executed. When CasperJS runs out of steps to execute and no function is passed into `casper.run()`, then it will automatically exit.

The easy fix would be to always pass an empty function into `casper.run()` and schedule new steps from inside the function:

```
casper.then(function(){
  var p = cp.execFile('/path/parse', [], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    casper.thenOpen(parsedUrl).then(function(){
      // do something on page
    });
  });
});
casper.run(function(){});
```

A more clean approach would be to write your own step function that wraps the `execFile` function:

```
casper.waitForFileExec = function(process, callback, onTimeout, timeout){
    this.then(function(){
        var cp = require('child_process'),
            finished = false,
            self = this;
        timeout = timeout === null || this.options.stepTimeout;
        cp.execFile(process, [], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            finished = true;
            callback.call(self, error, stdout, stderr);
        });
        this.waitFor(function check(){
            return finished;
        }, null, onTimeout, timeout);
    });
    return this; // for builder/promise pattern
};

...
casper.waitForFileExec('/path/parse', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    this.echo(stdout);
    this.thenOpen(parsedUrl).then(function(){
        // do something on page
    });
}).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.then(function(){
  var p = cp.execFile('/path/parse', [], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    casper.thenOpen(parsedUrl).then(function(){
      // do something on page
    });
  });
});
casper.run(function(){});
```

From my test, `capser.run` does not wait for `execFile` to finish the job. There is no log gets printed from the `execFile` callback. @Artjom B.