# The “exit” event doesn’t get triggered after spawning a node module (PhantomJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, child-process

**init.js**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

casper.start('http://google.com/', function () {

  // This works but it's not what I want.
  //var event = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/s', '/c', 'md foo']);

  var event = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/s', '/c', 'node builder']);

  event.on('exit', function () {

    console.log('Done.');

  });

});

casper.run();
```

**builder.js**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('cmd.exe', ['/s', '/c', 'md foo']);
```

The event “exit” doesn’t get triggered after spawning the node module.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

**Update**

Everything works as expected if I listen to the exit event outside of the start callback.

Comment: Have you tried to use `require('child_process').exec` instead of `require('child_process').spawn`? `spawn` is not asynchronous like you would expect.

Comment: I tried and the result is the same: builder.js executes the command but init.js doesn’t know that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253690/wait-for-a-child-process-in-casperjs The answer of *Artjom B.* fixed my problem.