# CasperJS + PhantomJS Child Process Does not work on Windows 7

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am new using CasperJS. I am trying to call an external command using Casper but nothing appers in the console. I am using Windows 7. Do you have any idea? This is the code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.then(function() {
 var process = require("child_process")
 var spawn = process.spawn
 var execFile = process.execFile            

 var child = spawn("cmd.exe", ["/k","dir"])

 child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log("spawnSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(data))
 })

 child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log("spawnSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(data))
 })

 child.on("exit", function (code) {
  console.log("spawnEXIT:", code)
 })
});     

casper.run();
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for a child process in CasperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253690/wait-for-a-child-process-in-casperjs)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because CasperJS exits earlier than spawned process manages to return data.

The detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29255476/2715393